# What is the opposite of commercial?

Tags: antonyms

What is the opposite of **commercial**?
Is  it "personal" or "public"? I want to use these terms for a dichotomous variable I have created.

**EDIT**:

I was trying to create a variable for trucks and passenger car but writing commercial for the trucks

Comment: "(TV) program". :-)  Seriously, "opposites" require context -- commercial vs. non-profit, vs. open-source, vs. personal, vs. residential (per JLG)...

Comment: You'll have to provide more context - what are you talking about that is commercial vs. non-commercial?

Comment: Thank you all especially @Monica (+1). I was trying to create a variable for trucks and passenger car but writing commercial for the trucks.

Comment: That detail should go into the  question.

Comment: If you write *[common carrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_carrier)* for the commercial vehicles, you could write *uncommon carrier* for the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-commercial: a general purpose antonym/ alternative widely used.

Any other 'opposite word' will be context-dependent.

.

Comment: +1 Per OP's comment on types of vehicle, and Wikipedia on driver's licenses in the United States, I would go with *non-commercial*, but advocate as a second choice *standard*.

Comment: commercial vehicles /  non-commercial vehicles.

Comment: If the tone of the speech is formal, this is right, but in practice "private vehicle" is used more frequently.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the opposite is *private*.

Comment: Given the context in the comments from the asker, you're obv. right.  I'm leaving this comment to note that you're answering the comment and that the question is ambiguous in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Often the opposite is *residential*, especially with businesses that service both companies and households.

Comment: The opposite of commercial is contextual, and the context specified  indicates this isn't its opposite. @cornbreadninja has the right answer below.

Comment: I wouldn't have answered without context. If it were me I might delete my answer as I didn't really answer the question.